# Apply data-binding to dom element in a custom data-binding

Tags: knockout.js

I have a custom data-bind like this :

```
ko.bindingHandlers.calendar = {
            init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
                var value = valueAccessor() || {};              
                var calType =  $('<select style=""><option value="gregorian">Miladi</option><option value="islamic">Hicri</option><option value="rumi">Rumi</option></select>');                                                             

                // Need to something to apply this binding for the calType variable
                calType['attr']('data-bind', 'chosen : true');   

                 ....
                 ....

                $(element).before(calType);
            }
};

ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
                init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
                    $(element).chosen();
                },
                update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
                    $(element).trigger("liszt:updated");
                }
};
```

I want to apply chosen binding on a dynamically created dom element inside the calendar binding. Is there any way to to this ?

Comment: quite complex... are you sure you need this ... ?

Comment: I can do it diffrently have you got any idea ?

Comment: Maybe it would be better to create all required elements in advance and map to some conditional properties in VM and then do actions in your custom binder or let ko to handle it. Write more details or ask more general question and we will find another approach how to resolve your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call "ko.applyBindings(viewModel);" after your dynamically created dom element is created.

Comment: Hi i checked your suggestion but that doesnt work. It gives me an exception that doesnt belong to this part of viewModel. "Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: Object #<HTMLTextAreaElement> has no method 'enabled';" ko.applyBindings(x) try to bind all viewModel but i only need that element. You have to consider that this code may run after the initial binding.

Comment: I tried ko.applyBindings(viewModel,x) too but got another exception. This time its about chosen plugin.Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of undefined
h.search_field_disabled. Have to dig chosen library to find out the actual problem.

Comment: At the end i can do it via ko.applyBindings(viewModel,x). Thanks for the clue.

Comment: Welcome, X was supposed to be your variable name of your view_model. It wasn't mentioned in the question. You should use ko.applyBindings(viewModel).